# Permissions required for sending messages through ms teams bot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to build a Microsoft teams messaging bot for sending/receiving messages. For my app, I noticed that I had to add application level API permissions for chat read/write scopes and get them approved in order to send bot messages to users.

However, I noticed that installing an app from the Microsoft teams app store (like Stack overflow for teams) worked right out of the box. It didn't require any additional approvals, etc. for their bot to send me a message.

My question is:
What permissions are required/bundled in that can allow bot to send user a message after user installs/adds app?

Comment: The apps present in MS Teams app stores are deployed apps already having required permissions enabled. Please refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent

Comment: Hi @Prasad-MSFT, thank you! I think it looks like I just had to add Microsoft Graph User.ReadWrite permissions under Azure Portal -> applications -> bot app -> API Permissions